# Divergence theorem and discontinuous vector fields in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, vector-fields

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) defines Gauss Divergence Theorem for a continuously differentiable vector field; but in many idealized physical situations, we use it for non-differentiable fields. For example, the electric field about a conductor is zero inside the conductor, but right at the boundary, it has a non-zero value (just like a step-function).

This may lead to erroneous results, and I want to check this idea by the means of an example.

Assume a sphere of volume $\mathbf{V}$, with volume and surface charge densities:

$$\rho_b = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{P} \ on \ V$$
$$\sigma_b = \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{ \hat n } \ on \ \Sigma V$$

Here, $\mathbf{P}$ is a vector field which has some non-zero value on $\Sigma \mathbf{V}$ and in $\mathbf{V}$, but is zero for all points out side the boundary of the sphere, i.e., it is a discontinuous field.

As can be verified, the total bound charge is zero.

Thus, if we assume a Gaussian shell $\mathbf{S}$ around this sphere, whose radius is slightly bigger than the sphere, but tending to the radius of the sphere, then we can apply Gauss's law and see that:

$$\int_S \mathbf{E} \cdot d \mathbf{a} = \frac {q_{enc}} {\epsilon_0}$$

which simplifies by using the fact that:

$$\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{\hat n} = E_{||} = \frac {\sigma_b} {\epsilon_0}$$

where $\sigma_b$ is a function of the vector $\mathbf{r'}$ which lies on the boundary of the sphere. Since, since $q_{enc} = 0$, thus:

$$\int_S E_{||} da = \int_S \frac {\sigma_b} {\epsilon_0} da = 0$$

But since any two shells are isomorphic in Euclidean space, hence, we can replace $da$ with $\lambda da'$, where $\lambda$ is a scaling factor. This scaling factor embodies the fact that we can project an area element $da$ from the shell to the boundary of the sphere, and we'll get a scaled down projection area element $da'$ on the surface of the sphere. The factor $\lambda \to 1$ as $\mathbf{S} \to \Sigma \mathbf{V}$.

Now, we can complete the integration to get:

$$\frac {\lambda} {\epsilon_0} \int_{\Sigma V} \sigma_b da' = 0$$

and thus:

$$\int_{\Sigma V} \sigma_b \  da' = 0$$

This implies that the total surface charge is zero, which isn't generally true.

So where did I make a wrong assumption? Or is this inconsistency because the field $\mathbf{P}$ is discontinuous?

$\bf{UPDATE:}$

This question has been answered by user $\bf{Kyson}$:

He pointed out that I was wrongly assuming $\vec{E}_{out}⋅n̂  = E_{||} = \frac {\sigma_b} {\epsilon_0}$, whereas this is correct only for a conductor. Since in my case, we don't have a conductor, the correct relation is:

$$(\vec{E}_{out} - \vec{E}_{in})⋅n̂  = \frac {σ_b} {ϵ_0}$$

which solves the inconsistency.

Comment: Why $\vec{E}\cdot\hat{n}=\sigma_b/\epsilon_0$?

Comment: @Kyson: The electric field close to the surface of a conductor is $\frac {\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$, where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density of the conductor. Since this field is perpendicular to the surface of the conductor, hence it equals $\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{\hat n}$.

Comment: You are considering a conductor or a polarized sphere? If it is a polarized sphere, then you are right that total charge = 0. If it is a conductor, then $\rho=0$ and the charge enclosed is the surface charge $\sigma$. And the total charge enclosed is not zero in general.

Comment: If you look carefully, the way I've defined the two charge densities, Divergence theorem can be used to see that the total charge in indeed $0$. Anyway, I started the question with a polarized sphere, but realized that by defining an arbitrary $\bf{P}$ vector, I can abstract away the core issue without the complication of polarization.

Comment: The E field inside the polarized sphere is nonzero. So it should be $(\vec{E}_\text{out}-\vec{E}_\text{in})\cdot \hat{n}=\sigma/\epsilon_0$.

Comment: @Kyson: I see. It seems like I assumed the sphere to be a conductor, and applied the $E$ field formula for a conductor, which is incorrect.